# PHP Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php

Insted;

SELECT * FROM payments WHERE `user_id` = 1 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1,1

Help me convert this into PDO Statements.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: "_you have an error in your SQL syntax_", so print your `$query` before preparing your statement, look at what you've made it generate, and then use that information to fix your code. Because right now it's generating "not valid SQL".

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
print_r($query);
```

now you will see the sql

go to phpmyadmin or mysql and place your sql

usually its an error of sql statement